# less.exe outputting incorrect characters

Tags: python, windows, character-encoding

The following program is very simple. It launches a subprocess which runs a [Windows port of the Unix utility **less**](http://adoxa.altervista.org/less/index.html).

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('less.exe', input='Macarrão é uma delícia.', encoding='utf-8')
```

The input is:

```
Macarrão é uma delícia.
```

The output, though, comes out as:

```
Macarr├úo ├⌐ uma del├¡cia.
```

What is the explanation for this? I have noticed that running `chcp 65001` before running my python code fixes the problem, but looking through a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47843552/2592879) I'm not sure it's the best way to go about it. Quoting from the accepted answer:

> chcp 65001 is very dangerous. Unless a program was specially designed
>   to work around defects in the Windows’ API (or uses a C runtime
>   library which has these workarounds), it would not work reliably.
>   [Win8 fixes ½ of these problems with `cp65001`, but the rest is still
>   applicable to Win10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39745938/9106292).

I'm running Python 3.7.0 on Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: less.exe apparently uses the legacy console interface via `WriteFile` or `WriteConsoleA`, which depends on the current console codepage. You can temporarily switch the codepage with a try/finally statement. Get the current codepage via `GetConsoleOutputCP()`; set the new codepage via `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)`; `try` to run less.exe; and `finally` restore  the old codepage. Setting the console output codepage to UTF-8 works fine in Windows 8+. It's buggy in Windows 7 when used with buffered writers such as C `FILE` streams and Python file objects.

Comment: @eryksun I see. Could you post that as answer with an example on how to do what you're talking about in python?

Comment: Use ctypes. These are simple calls, so we don't even need to define prototypes. The setup is `import ctypes;` `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)`. Then you can call the functions I mentioned as attributes, e.g. `prev_codepage = kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP()`.

Comment: @ErykSun Just out of curiosity, since WriteFile is not appropriate for Unicode, which function should be have been used?

Comment: `WriteFile` is generally fine for Unicode, as long we're writing a Unicode transport format such as UTF-8 or UTF-16. It's just encoded bytes.

Comment: That said, with the console in particular, its input and and screen buffers are UTF-16 (actually UCS-2), so UTF-8 has to be transcoded to UTF-16. Prior to Windows 8, when writing UTF-8 to a screen buffer, the console would mistakenly return the number of UTF-16 codes written instead of the number of UTF-8 bytes written, which is dysfunctional for a buffered writer such as a C `FILE` a stream. For reading input it's worse, even in Windows 10. The console does not support encoding non-ASCII characters as UTF-8, so the input codepage should never be set to UTF-8 via `SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8)`.

Comment: The alternative for the best possible Unicode support is to use the console's wide-character API, such as `ReadConsoleW` and `WriteConsoleW`. This API works with the native UTF-16 strings of Windows, so it avoids the problems the console has when transcoding UTF-8 to UTF-16. Bear in mind that the console is still primarily limited to UCS-2 -- i.e. the basic multilingual plane, non-complex scripts, and precomposed characters. The new Terminal application in Windows has broader Unicode support, such as for non-BMP characters such as emojis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by eryk, one way is to set the console codepage to UTF-8, run less.exe and set the codepage back to what it was previously.

```
import subprocess
from ctypes import windll

prev_codepage = windll.kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP()
windll.kernel32.SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)
subprocess.run("less.exe", input='Macarrão é uma delícia', encoding='utf-8')
windll.kernel32.SetConsoleOutputCP(prev_codepage)
```

Comment: But in general do not use `windll` in libraries. It caches `WinDLL` instances, which cache function pointer instances, which leads to prototype conflicts between packages. It also doesn't allow setting `use_last_error=True` for getting the last error *reliably* via `ctypes.get_last_error()`.

Answer (score 0):

To complement [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55672795/45375) with a simpler alternative - although I don't understand *why* it works; tested on Windows 10 with Python 3.8:

```
import os
os.system('echo Macarrão é uma delícia.| less.exe')
```

On Windows, [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) calls `cmd.exe` (via env. var. `ComSpec`) and even though a `cmd.exe` instance created this way still reports the system's OEM code page as the active code page, the command works as desired.