# java utf8 export jar

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8

How can I export as jar with utf8 encoding? When I export my project to JAR file, the I run jar file on command line it shows quesion marks. How can I fix it?

```
package utf8JAVA;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String s = "ıııııəəəə";
        String UTF8Str = new String(s.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(UTF8Str);
    }

}
```

Comment: After creating the jar file, while running the jar file from command use this -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8", it will work.

Comment: It doesn;t works. My command is: java -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -jar test.jar

Comment: Can you try with java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar test.jar, just remove the quotes.

Comment: `new String(s.getBytes(), "UTF-8")` is very wrong.  All Strings have the same encoding (UTF-16).  Where are you seeing question marks?  Is it in a command window in Windows?

Comment: Yes questions shows on command line

Comment: What do you use for command line? Windows `cmd.exe` does not support utf8 by default, you would have to use a special configuration

Comment: I also tested on powersheel same result

Comment: you can check this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503588/text-utf-8-in-console-works-in-eclipse-but-fails-to-work-with-an-exported-jar

Comment: Right after creating `s`, add `System.out.println(s.codePointAt(0));`.  If it prints `305`, your String is correct and your file is correct, and you should not be messing with bytes;  the problem is that a Windows command prompt cannot display those characters.

Comment: Until you remove `new String(s.getBytes(), "UTF-8")` there is no need for further testing. Ask if you have questions about that.